# Right continuous Stochastic process $A$ increasing on countable dense subset of $[0,1]$ has increasing trajectories on $[0,1]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

I am currently reading through the proof of the Doob-Meyer deocomposition and came across this statement:

> Assume that $(A_t)_{t \in [0,1]}$ is a right continuous stochastic process. If $D$ is a countable dense subset of $[0,1]$, e.g. $D=\mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]$, and for all $t,t' \in D$ with $t \leq t'$ we have
>   $$A_t \leq A_t' \text{,   P-a.s. }, $$
>   Then the trajectories of $A$ are almost surely increasing, i.e. the set
>   $$\{\omega: t \mapsto A_t(\omega) \text{ is increasing}\}$$
>   contains a set of probability one.

I do not know how to prove this statement, since it was not proved inside the proof, so I assume it should be easy. But I still cannot see why it holds. Does anyone know how to prove this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the set of rationals is countable, the inequality you have holds almost surely for all rational $t, t'$. Note the difference in the position of the quantifier "almost surely" between your inequality and what I stated above.

Then fix some $\omega$ in this full measure set and two arbitrary time points $t<s$. Since the paths are right-continuous, you can express $A_t(\omega)$ as $\lim A_{t_n}(\omega)$ with $t_n$ rational for every $n$. You can do the same for $A_s(\omega)$. Since $A_{t_n}(\omega) \leq A_{s_n}(\omega)$ (you can choose your sequences to make sure this is true), it follows that $A_{t}(\omega) \leq A_{s}(\omega)$.